# How to see if two variables are not equal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I knew that you can check if variables are equal with = or ==, but can you check if it is less than or greater that with < >, but is there a way to check if two variables are not equal, but instead diffrent

Comment: You would be better served reading a book.  _"[The problem with 'too broad' questions is that they tend to get a book-style answer. That is exactly the kind of answer that SE wants to avoid.  Learning something takes a **book**, or a good set of **tutorials**. SE sites, and Stack Overflow in particular, aren't that. They are a knowledge base of to-the-point questions and answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275238/585968)"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most modern programming languages, this is accomplished with the use of the ! in front of the = sign as in !=

`a != b` (Used in C# and others)

Or

`a <> b` (Useful if your program is using additional languages)

and sometimes you use it like

`NOT a == b` (Again, useful if your program is calling another language that uses this form.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the not equal to `!=` operator?

```
if (a != b)
{

}
```